# Using a qualified seal certificate issued on a SafeNet token for unattended operations in Java

Tags: java, x509certificate, safenet

As part of a larger project, a test module has been developed and is intended to be integrated into a tomcat-based Java webapp for unattended signing of large batches of documents using a qualified seal certificate that can be issued only on SafeNet tokens.

When running in debug configurations and the token is connected to the local machine (Windows), documents are signed properly.

When running on a remote server (also Windows), the token, attached to the server, is not detected.

There are two things that have been noticed :

1. the token is detected by the remote webapp code when attached locally and a remote desktop session to the server is active (this may be due to remote desktop config)
2. the token is detected by the webapp code when attached to the server only if a GUI session is active

Is it possible to make the token accessible to the webapp code when connected on the server without an active session ?